# s2-quickstart ERROR hbm2ddl

Tags: grails, spring-security

Running into some errors with the Spring Sec Plugin, straight off-the-bat:

```
Grails version: 2.4.0
> grails create-app foo
| Created Grails Application at /private/tmp/foo
>
> # add sec plugin dependency
> vim foo/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
> grep spring-sec foo/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"
> cd foo
> grails refresh-dependencies
| Installed plugin spring-security-core-2.0-RC3

*******************************************************
* You've installed the Spring Security Core plugin.   *
*                                                     *
* Next run the "s2-quickstart" script to initialize   *
* Spring Security and create your domain classes.     *
*                                                     *
*******************************************************
| Dependencies refreshed.
>
> grails s2-quickstart com.foo.auth Person Authority
| Compiling 10 source files

| Compiling 183 source files
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
|
*******************************************************
* Created security-related domain classes. Your       *
* grails-app/conf/Config.groovy has been updated with *
* the class names of the configured domain classes;   *
* please verify that the values are correct.          *
*******************************************************

>
> grails run-app
| Running Grails application
objc[22764]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
| Error 2014-06-06 14:32:18,918 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table person_authority drop constraint FK_7d2mdh76otecbaoaq5y9p12ar if exists
| Error 2014-06-06 14:32:18,961 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "PERSON_AUTHORITY" not found; SQL statement:
alter table person_authority drop constraint FK_7d2mdh76otecbaoaq5y9p12ar if exists [42102-173]
| Error 2014-06-06 14:32:18,961 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table person_authority drop constraint FK_kdi2d7ujicv663k0h6mv85jx3 if exists
| Error 2014-06-06 14:32:18,961 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "PERSON_AUTHORITY" not found; SQL statement:
alter table person_authority drop constraint FK_kdi2d7ujicv663k0h6mv85jx3 if exists [42102-173]
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/foo
```

I'm quite sure the schema doesn't get created (in another attempt, I've enabled /dbConsole routing, and didn't see the expected 'PERSON'/'AUTHORITY'/... tables there.

Any thoughts?
Thanks,